# Can I build a Maven archetypes or Sample Project?

Tags: java, maven, spring-webflow

Can I build a Maven archetypes or Sample Project?...  What I am looking for is that I setup project templates for other developers in my firm to you and I would like to know if somehow I can setup a template for a project and put it in my repo for other develpers to get?

is this something that I should be doing??

Comment: Start here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you be able to? You can design an archetype relatively simply (I've never done it though!). You could start here:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's more simple to create archetype from an existing project, see documentation:

- http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/create-multi-module-project.html
- http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html

That will generate an archetype skeleton from your project then you will be able to improve it.

### HTH

Olivier